# Created a deque class, but unable to declare within my binary tree class method

Tags: c++, xcode, class, compiler-errors, binary-tree

Could someone help me with this, as an on-going personal interest I've working on creating a binary tree class, and have also created my own deque class `dequeList`, that I want to use within my binary tree class `FibTree`, I'm very much a novice C++ programmer and having difficulty with the fundamentals.

I've created a binary tree of Fibonacci numbers and I'm trying to write out sets, and I'm using the methods `startWriteSets` and `writeSets` to do this; my problem is that I'm trying to declare a new `dequeList` with the `startWriteSets` method, then pass this to the `writeSets` method, but Im getting compile errors; could someone help me utilise my `dequeList` without compilation errors, I'm using Xcode 3.2.2.

**Compile errors:**
`Compile main.cpp
'dequeList has not been declared`

`Compile deque.cpp
'dequeList has not been declared`

`Compile fibtree.cpp
'dequeList has not been declared`

`Compile fibtree.cpp
'dequeList has not been declared`

`error: no matching function for call to 'FibTree::writeSets(dequeList*&, const FibTree::Node*&)'`

`note: candidates are: void FibTree::writeSets(int*&, const FibTree::Node*)`

`error: prototype for 'void FibTree::writeSets(dequeList*&, const FibTree::Node*)' does not match any in class 'FibTree'`

`error: candidate is: void FibTree::writeSets(int*&, const FibTree::Node*)`

`error: 'setsList' was not declared in this scope`

`error: 'setsList' was not declared in this scope`

My code is listed below, with errors:

**deque.h**

```
/*
 *  deque.h
 *  fibonacci / deque / interface
 *  deque holding FibTree::Node datatype
 *  using a double-linked list implementation
 */

#ifndef DEQUE_H
#define DEQUE_H

#include "fibtree.h"

class dequeNode {
public:
    dequeNode* prev;
    dequeNode* next;
    FibTree::Node const* data;

    dequeNode( void );
    dequeNode( FibTree::Node const* );

};

class dequeList {
public:
    dequeNode* firstNode;
    dequeNode* lastNode;

    dequeList( void );

    void enque( FibTree::Node const* );
    void enqueFront( FibTree::Node const* );

    FibTree::Node const* deque( void );
    FibTree::Node const* dequeFront( void );
    bool isEmpty( void );

private:
    void insertAfter( dequeList* list, dequeNode* node, dequeNode* newNode );
    void insertBefore( dequeList* list, dequeNode* node, dequeNode* newNode );
    void insertBeginning( dequeList* list, dequeNode* newNode );
    void insertEnd( dequeList* list, dequeNode* newNode );
    void removeNode( dequeList* list, dequeNode* node );

    dequeNode* frontNode( dequeList* list ); // examine front
    dequeNode* backNode( dequeList* list ); // examine back
    void popFront( dequeList* list ); // delete first
    void popBack( dequeList* list ); // delete last
    void pushBack( dequeList* list, FibTree::Node const* n );
    void pushFront( dequeList* list, FibTree::Node const* n );

};

#endif
```

**deque.cpp**

```
/*
 *  deque.cpp
 *  fibonacci / deque / implementation
 *
 */

#include "deque.h"
#include <cstddef>

// Constructors
dequeNode::dequeNode()
: prev( NULL ), next( NULL ), data( NULL )
{
};

dequeNode::dequeNode( FibTree::Node const* n )
: prev( NULL ), next( NULL ), data( n )
{
};

dequeList::dequeList()
: firstNode( NULL ), lastNode( NULL )
{
};

// Public Methods
void dequeList::enque( FibTree::Node const* n ) {
    pushBack( this, n );
}

void dequeList::enqueFront( FibTree::Node const* n ) {
    pushFront( this, n );
}

const FibTree::Node* dequeList::deque( void ) {
    dequeNode* node = frontNode( this );
    const FibTree::Node* data = node->data;
    popFront( this );
    return data;
}

bool dequeList::isEmpty( void ) {
    if ( this->firstNode == NULL && this->lastNode == NULL ) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }

}

// Private methods
void dequeList::insertAfter( dequeList* list, dequeNode* node, dequeNode* newNode ) {
    newNode->prev = node;
    newNode->next = node->next;
    if ( node->next == NULL ) {
        list->lastNode = newNode;
    } else {
        node->next->prev = newNode;
    }
    node->next = newNode;

}

void dequeList::insertBefore( dequeList* list, dequeNode* node, dequeNode* newNode ) {
    newNode->prev = node->prev;
    newNode->next = node;
    if ( node->prev == NULL ) {
        list->firstNode = newNode;
    } else {
        node->prev->next = newNode;
    }
    node->prev = newNode;

}

void dequeList::insertBeginning( dequeList* list, dequeNode* newNode ){
    if ( list->firstNode == NULL ) {
        list->firstNode = newNode;
        list->lastNode = newNode;
        newNode->prev = NULL;
        newNode->next = NULL;
    } else {
        insertBefore( list , list->firstNode, newNode );
    }

}

void dequeList::insertEnd( dequeList* list, dequeNode* newNode ){
    if (list->lastNode == NULL) {
        insertBeginning( list, newNode );
    } else {
        insertAfter( list, list->lastNode, newNode );
    }
}

void dequeList::removeNode( dequeList* list, dequeNode* node ) { // pop_front / pop_back
    if (node->prev == NULL) {
        list->firstNode = node->next;
    } else {
        node->prev->next = node->next;
    }
    if (node->next == NULL) {
        list->lastNode = node->prev;
    } else {
        node->next->prev = node->prev;
    }
    delete node;

}

dequeNode* dequeList::frontNode( dequeList* list ) { // Examine first
    return list->lastNode;
}

dequeNode* dequeList::backNode( dequeList* list ) { // Examine last
    return list->firstNode;
}

void dequeList::popFront( dequeList* list ) { // Delete first
    removeNode(list, list->lastNode);
}

void dequeList::popBack( dequeList* list ) { // Delete last
    removeNode(list, list->firstNode);
}

void dequeList::pushBack( dequeList* list, FibTree::Node const* n ) { // Append (Enque)
    dequeNode* newNode = new dequeNode( n );
    insertBeginning(list, newNode);
}

void dequeList::pushFront( dequeList* list, FibTree::Node const* n ) { // Prepend
    dequeNode* newNode = new dequeNode( n );
    insertEnd(list, newNode);
}
```

**fibtree.h**

```
/*
 *  fibtree.h
 *  Fibonacci binary tree / interface
 *
 */

#ifndef FIBTREE_H
#define FIBTREE_H

#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "deque.h"

class FibTree {

public:
    class Node {
    public:
        int data;
        Node const* left;
        Node const* right;
        Node const* parent;
        int n;
        int level;
        int index;

        Node (void);

        bool isLeftChild(void) const;
        bool isRightChild(void) const;
        bool isLeafNode(void) const;
        bool hasLeftChild(void) const;
        bool hasRightChild(void) const;
        bool hasParent(void) const;
    };

    Node const* root; // 'root' pointer to constant Node

    FibTree (int);

    Node const* getRoot(void); // Getters
    int getHeight(Node const* root);

    void preOrder(Node const* root); // Tree traversals
    void preOrderFormatted(Node const* root, std::string indent = "");
    void inOrder(Node const* root);
    void postOrder(Node const* root);

    void breadthFirst(Node const* root);
    void levelOrderBreadthFirst(Node const* root);
    void loBFStructured(Node const* root);

    void writeFibTree(Node const* root); // Serialisation
    ***error: 'dequeList' has not been declared***

    void startWriteSets(Node const* root); // Write all sets of tree
    void writeSets(dequeList* &leftQueue, Node const* cur); // Used by startWriteSets

    int countNodes(Node const* root); // Node counting
    int countLeafNodes(Node const* root);
    int countInteriorNodes(Node const* root);


private:
    static Node* buildTree( int n, int level = 0, int i = 1, Node* parent = NULL );
    void printNode (Node const* root);

};

#endif
```

**fibfree.cpp**

```
/*
*  fibtree.cpp
*  Fibonacci binary tree / implementation
*
*/

#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include "deque.h"
#include "fibtree.h"

// FibTree Constructor
FibTree::FibTree(int n) {
    this->root = buildTree( n );
};

// Getters
FibTree::Node const* FibTree::getRoot(void) {
    return this->root;
}

int FibTree::getHeight( Node const* root ) {
    if( root == NULL || root->isLeafNode() ) {
        return 0;
    }
    return std::max(getHeight(root->left), getHeight(root->right)) + 1; 

}

// Traversals
void FibTree::preOrder(Node const* root) { // Preorder Depth First Traversal (root, left, right)
    if (root == NULL)
        return;
    printNode(root);
    preOrder(root->left);
    preOrder(root->right);
}

void FibTree::preOrderFormatted(Node const* root, std::string indent ) { // Pre-order formatted

    if (root != NULL) {
        std::cout << indent;
        if ( !root->isLeafNode() ) {
            std::cout << "|-";
            indent += "| ";
        } else {
            std::cout << "\\-";
            indent += " ";
        }
        if ( root->isLeftChild() ) {
            std::cout << root->data << " [L]" << " i=" << root->index << std::endl;
        } else if ( root->parent != NULL ) {
            std::cout << root->data << " [R]" << " i=" << root->index << std::endl;
        } else {
            std::cout << root->data << " i=" << root->index << std::endl;
        }

        if ( root->hasLeftChild() ) {
            preOrderFormatted( root->left, indent );
        }
        if ( root->hasRightChild() ) {
            preOrderFormatted( root->right, indent );
        }

    }
}

void FibTree::inOrder(Node const* root) { // Inorder (Symetric) Depth First Traversal (left, root, right); producing a sorted sequence.
    if (root == NULL)
        return;
    inOrder(root->left);
    printNode(root);
    inOrder(root->right);
}

void FibTree::postOrder(Node const* root) { // Postorder Depth First Traversal (left, right, root).
    if (root == NULL)
        return;
    postOrder(root->left);
    postOrder(root->right);
    printNode(root);
}

void FibTree::breadthFirst(Node const* root) { // Breadth-first traversal
    dequeList* list = new dequeList();
    list->enque(root);
    while ( !list->isEmpty() ) {
        Node const* node = list->deque();
        printNode( node );
        if ( node->hasLeftChild() ) {
            list->enque( node->left );
        }
        if ( node->hasRightChild() ) {
            list->enque( node->right );
        }

    }
}

void FibTree::levelOrderBreadthFirst(Node const* root) { // Level-order Breadth-first traversal
    dequeList* thisLevel = new dequeList();

    thisLevel->enque(root);

    while ( !thisLevel->isEmpty() ) { 

        dequeList* nextLevel = new dequeList();

        dequeNode* thisNode = thisLevel->lastNode; // iterate thisLevel
        while ( thisNode != NULL ) {
            printNode( thisNode->data );
            thisNode = thisNode->prev;
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;

        while ( !thisLevel->isEmpty() ) { // get next level
            Node const* node = thisLevel->deque();

            if ( node->hasLeftChild() ) {
                nextLevel->enque( node->left );
            }
            if ( node->hasRightChild() ) {
                nextLevel->enque( node->right );
            }
        }

        thisLevel = nextLevel;
    }
}

void FibTree::loBFStructured(Node const* root) { // Level-order Breadth-first traversal structured output
    // Each node is centred above it's children

    // Calculate width of of each node:
    // Amount of Hoz space required to display this node's entire subtree, 
    // such that it doesn't overlap with it's left or right siblings' subtree

    // width = 1 + sum (width of children's nodes)

    // DF traversal through tree to calc each node's width

    // To display: LOBF traversal
    dequeList* thisLevel = new dequeList();

    thisLevel->enque(root);

    while ( !thisLevel->isEmpty() ) { 

        dequeList* nextLevel = new dequeList();

        dequeNode* thisNode = thisLevel->lastNode; // iterate thisLevel

        while ( thisNode != NULL ) {
            int width = countNodes(thisNode->data);

            width +=2;

            while(width--)
                std::putchar(' ');

            std::cout << thisNode->data->data << '(' << thisNode->data->index << ')';
            thisNode = thisNode->prev;
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;

        while ( !thisLevel->isEmpty() ) { // get next level
            Node const* node = thisLevel->deque();

            if ( node->hasLeftChild() ) {
                nextLevel->enque( node->left );
            }
            if ( node->hasRightChild() ) {
                nextLevel->enque( node->right );
            }
        }

        thisLevel = nextLevel;
    }

}



// Serialisation
void FibTree::writeFibTree(Node const* root) { // Preorder tree serialisation method    
    if ( root == NULL ) {
        std::cout << "# ";
        return;
    } else {
        std::cout << root->data << " ";
        writeFibTree( root->left );
        writeFibTree( root->right );
    }
}

// Write sets of tree
void FibTree::startWriteSets(Node const* root) {
    //std::vector<Node const*> setsList;

    dequeList* leftQueue = new dequeList();

    std::cout << root->data << '(' << root->index << ')' << ',';
    writeSets(leftQueue, root);
    ***error: no matching function for call to 'FibTree::writeSets(dequeList*&, const FibTree::Node*&)'***
}

//void FibTree::writeSets(std::vector<Node const*> &setsList, Node const* cur) {
void FibTree::writeSets(dequeList* &leftQueue, Node const* cur) {
    ***error: prototype for 'void FibTree::writeSets(dequeList*&, const FibTree::Node*)' does not match any in class 'FibTree'***

    std::vector<Node const*>::iterator nodeIterator;
    std::cout << '(';

    if (! setsList.empty()) { ***error: 'setsList' was not declared in this scope***

        setsList.pop_front();
    }

    // Displays all preceding left values
    for (nodeIterator = setsList.begin(); nodeIterator != setsList.end(); nodeIterator++) { ***error: 'setsList' was not declared in this scope***



        std::cout << (*nodeIterator)->data << '(' << (*nodeIterator)->index << ')' << ',';
    }

    if (cur->hasLeftChild()) {
        std::cout << cur->left->data << '(' << cur->left->index << ')' << ',';
        setsList.push_back(cur->left);
    }
    if (cur->hasRightChild()) {
        std::cout << cur->right->data << '(' << cur->right->index << ')' << ',';

        writeSets(setsList,cur->right);

    }
    setsList.pop_back();
    std::cout << ')';


}


// Node counting
int FibTree::countNodes(Node const* root) { // Count all tree nodes
    int count = 0;

    if ( root->hasLeftChild() )
        count += countNodes(root->left);

    if ( root->hasRightChild() )
        count += countNodes(root->right);

    count += 1;
    return count;

}

int FibTree::countLeafNodes(Node const* root) { // count all leaf nodes
    // An almost complete strictly binary tree with n leafs has 2n - 1 nodes
    int count = 0;

    if ( root->hasLeftChild() )
        count += countLeafNodes(root->left);

    if ( root->hasRightChild() )
        count += countLeafNodes(root->right);

    if (!root->hasLeftChild() && !root->hasRightChild())
        count += 1;
    return count;
}

int FibTree::countInteriorNodes(Node const* root) { // Return number of internal nodes in tree
    int count = 0;

    if ( root->hasLeftChild() )
        count += countInteriorNodes(root->left);

    if ( root->hasRightChild() )
        count += countInteriorNodes(root->right);

    if ( (root->hasLeftChild() || root->hasRightChild()) && root->hasRightChild() )
        count += 1;
    return count;
}

// Private FibTree methods
FibTree::Node* FibTree::buildTree( int n, int level, int i, Node* parent ) { // Build Tree structure
    Node* thisNode = new Node();
    thisNode->n = n;
    thisNode->level = level;
    thisNode->index = i;
    thisNode->parent = parent;
    if (n < 2) {
        thisNode->left = NULL;
        thisNode->right = NULL;
        thisNode->data = n;
        return thisNode;
    } else {
        thisNode->left = buildTree( n - 1 , level + 1, i*2, thisNode );
        thisNode->right = buildTree( n - 2, level + 1, i*2+1, thisNode );
        thisNode->data = thisNode->left->data + thisNode->right->data;
        return thisNode;

    }
}

void FibTree::printNode(Node const* node) {
    std::cout << node->data << "[" << node->index << "]" << " ";
}


// FibTree Node constructor
FibTree::Node::Node()
: data( 0 ),
left( NULL ),
right( NULL ),
parent( NULL ),
n( 0 ),
level( 0 ),
index( 0 )
{
};

bool FibTree::Node::isLeftChild(void) const { // a pointer (Root) to const parameter, can only call const methods on it
    bool hasParent = this->parent != NULL;

    if ( hasParent ) {
        return this == this->parent->left;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

bool FibTree::Node::isRightChild(void) const {
    bool hasParent = this->parent != NULL;

    if ( hasParent ) {
        return this == this->parent->right;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

bool FibTree::Node::isLeafNode(void) const {
    if (this->left == NULL && this->right == NULL) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }

}

bool FibTree::Node::hasLeftChild(void) const {
    if ( this->left != NULL ) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

bool FibTree::Node::hasRightChild(void) const {
    if ( this->right != NULL ) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

bool FibTree::Node::hasParent(void) const {
    if ( this->parent != NULL ) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>

#include "deque.h"
#include "fibtree.h"

int main (int argc, const char* argv[]) {


    if (argc > 1) {

        int n = atoi( argv[1] ); // convert string to int
        FibTree f(n);
        //f.preOrder(f.getRoot());
        std::cout << "All Nodes count: " << f.countNodes(f.getRoot()) << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Leaf Nodes count: " << f.countLeafNodes(f.getRoot()) << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Interior Nodes count: " << f.countInteriorNodes(f.getRoot()) << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Tree Height: " << f.getHeight(f.getRoot()) << std::endl;
        //f.writeFibTree(f.getRoot());

        f.loBFStructured(f.getRoot());

        f.startWriteSets(f.getRoot());

        std::cout << std::endl;


    }

    return 0;

}
```

Any insights as to where I'm fundamentally going wrong would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks in advance.

Alex

Comment: You have a circular inclusion/dependency. deque.h include "fibtree.h" and fibtree.h includes "deque.h."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a [**circular dependency**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_dependency) issue, causing the includes not to work as you expect.

**Explanations:**

In `main.cpp` you include `deque.h`.  But `deque.h` includes itself `fibtree.h` before declaring anything.  Unfortunatley `FibTree` class needs `dequeList`, so the header includes itself `deque.h` at its beginning.  As `DEQUE_H` is already defined at this moment, the file IS NOT included again.  When encoutering the first use of `dequeList` in `fibtree.h`, this class is not yet defined ! Hence the error.

**Solution:**

When you have two interdependent classes, you need to use a forward declaration.

To solve this, you could just add in `fibtree.h` the following line before the `FibTree` definition:

```
class dequeList;   // Forward declaration
```

As in this file you do not refer to a `dequeList` object but only to a pointer to a `dequeList`, this forward declaration will be sufficient for the compiler to know that your class exist.  Your FibTree class can then be completely defined, and then your compiler can process the dequeList header.  Et voilà !

Comment: many thanks, didn't think beyond the FibTree class. I can move forward with this now.